# AWK - Is there a way to match partially a numeric string?

Tags: regex, bash, awk, matching

I'm having some trouble with matching some lines with a numeric constant (given by an argument). For instance, given the following data in a file:

```
0.6880228954232877  0.2284901699470367  0.3868277922222205   T   T   T
0.7303175733143661  0.3618318512370564  0.3974056922222218   T   T   T
0.0000000000000000  0.0000000000000000  0.0000000000000000   T   T   T
0.0000000000000000  0.3333333333333357  0.0000000000000000   T   T   T
0.0000000000000000  0.6666666666666643  0.0000000000000000   T   T   T
0.8333728559007199  0.8332938107659444  0.0000000000000000   T   T   T
0.5226283985455709  0.2857115516559929  2.3313236566666689   T   T   T
0.1621334092166649  0.4671478452296256  2.3549492962962972   T   T   T
0.6160582554738738  0.3498000553315919  2.3391425111111133   T   T   T
0.7070022591099487  0.3040360596000298  2.3690645440740710   T   T   T
0.5183050106710922  0.2156253703264568  2.2883209644444449   T   T   T
0.5226283985455709  0.2857115516559929  3.3313236566666689   T   T   T
0.1621334092166649  0.4671478452296256  3.3549492962962972   T   T   T
0.6160582554738738  0.3498000553315919  3.3391425111111133   T   T   T
0.7070022591099487  0.3040360596000298  3.3690645440740710   T   T   T
0.5183050106710922  0.2156253703264568  3.2883209644444449   T   T   T
```

I would like to match lines whose third field starts with "2.", and then a simple substitution of the letters "T" to "F" for that lines.

I've tried several attempts but failed, with awk, for instance:
(Note that the first $1 is the bash argument that gives the pattern "2.".

```
 awk -v pattern=$1 ' $3 ~ pattern { print $1,$2,$3" F F F"  }' file
```

Does not work.

An alternative I've tried is instead of being the pattern "2.", just be "2", so the expression becomes:

```
 awk -v pattern=$1 ' $3 ~ /pattern\./ { print $1,$2,$3" F F F"  }' file
```

But it does not work either. Any suggestion greatly appreciated.

Comment: If none of the suggestions you already received help you need to explain how exactly what you have "does not work".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I hope I understand your question correctly. I don't get why you assign variable `pattern`, but never used it.

with your example data, this line works:

```
 awk '$3~/^2/&&$4=$5=$6="F"' file
```

or

```
awk '$3~/^2/{gsub(/T/,"F");print}' file
```

output:

```
kent$  awk '$3~/^2/&&$4=$5=$6="F"' file   
0.5226283985455709 0.2857115516559929 2.3313236566666689 F F F
0.1621334092166649 0.4671478452296256 2.3549492962962972 F F F
0.6160582554738738 0.3498000553315919 2.3391425111111133 F F F
0.7070022591099487 0.3040360596000298 2.3690645440740710 F F F
0.5183050106710922 0.2156253703264568 2.2883209644444449 F F F
```

or

```
kent$  awk '$3~/^2/{gsub(/T/,"F");print}' file
0.5226283985455709  0.2857115516559929  2.3313236566666689   F   F   F
0.1621334092166649  0.4671478452296256  2.3549492962962972   F   F   F
0.6160582554738738  0.3498000553315919  2.3391425111111133   F   F   F
0.7070022591099487  0.3040360596000298  2.3690645440740710   F   F   F
0.5183050106710922  0.2156253703264568  2.2883209644444449   F   F   F
```

**EDIT**

```
awk -v p="^2" '$3~p{gsub(/T/,"F");print}' file
```

if your pattern was stored in a shell var:

```
pattern="^2"
awk -v p="$pattern" '$3~p{gsub(/T/,"F");print}' file
```

Comment: Also, if `pattern="2"` then match with `$3 ~ "^"p`

Answer (score 1):

The following works for me in `gnu awk`

```
awk -v pattern='^2\\.' ' $3 ~ pattern {print($0)}' samp.t
0.5226283985455709  0.2857115516559929  2.3313236566666689   T   T   T
0.1621334092166649  0.4671478452296256  2.3549492962962972   T   T   T
0.6160582554738738  0.3498000553315919  2.3391425111111133   T   T   T
0.7070022591099487  0.3040360596000298  2.3690645440740710   T   T   T
0.5183050106710922  0.2156253703264568  2.2883209644444449   T   T   T
```

Comment: Or `awk -v pattern=2 'BEGIN { regex= "^" pattern "\." } $3 ~ regex { print ... }'`

Comment: @tripleee if you use dynamic regex, you need `regex="^" p "\\."`

Answer (score 1):

Your mistake is probably that you create a variable `pattern`, but use a variable `zlevel`. Also you need to anchor the expression (`^` to match the beginning of the string), otherwise any line containing `2` would be matched. The following should work:

```
e="2\."
awk -v pattern="^${e//\\/\\\\}" '$3 ~ pattern {gsub(/T/, "F", $0); print}'
```

`${e//\\/\\\\}` is just for escaping backslashes, so the regular expression doesn't become more complicated than necessary.

Comment: Sorry, It was a mistake for writing here at Stackexchange. pattern is the name to go. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: You also need to anchor the expression if you want to match fields starting with a particular number.

Answer (score 1):

The following awk will allow printing of lines starting where third column starts with 2.; you can then replace T to F as you like.

```
awk '{
if ($3 ~ "^2\..*") { print $0 }
}'
```

Also, sed may be a better fit for this problem (since this is a search replace type problem):

Something like this could do what you want:

```
sed 's/\(.*\) \(.*\) \(2\.[0-9]*\) \(.*\)/\1 \2 \3   F   F   F/g'
```